# Es posible cargar una lista de palabras en un arreglo desde un archivo de texto?

Tags: c++

Hola pues como dice la pregunta lo que quiero saber es si es posible cargar una lista de palabras en un arreglo de la forma que lo estoy haciendo.
Si alguien me puede ayudar por favor aquí esta un fragmento del código:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<synchapi.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    FILE *cargar_verbos; 
    int c_v=0;// este lo utilizo como contador
    string c__v; // este lo utilizo para cargar la palabra
    cargar_verbos=fopen("verbos_ar.txt","r"); 
    // el siguiente while lo utilizo para saber cuantas palabras hay en el              
    //archivo pues en este punto no tenemos ni idea.
    while(!feof(cargar_verbos))
    {
        fscanf(cargar_verbos,"%s",&c__v);
        c_v++; // por eso uso este contador

    }
    string verbos_ar[c_v]; //declaro el arreglo tipo string y utilizo el 
    //contador para declarar la cantidad



    c_v=0; // paso el contador nuevamente a cero

    while(!feof(cargar_verbos)) // aqui es donde tengo el problema
    {

        fscanf(cargar_verbos,"%s",&verbos_ar[c_v]); // esta es mi duda

        c_v++;

    }
    fclose(cargar_verbos);
    }
```

Como pueden observar en la parte que carga la palabra en el arreglo puse el contador como indicativo y según yo debería almacenar la palabra sin problemas pero siempre que ejecuto el programa y llega a esa parte me da error.
Si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho de verdad.

Comment: Cuando sales del primer bucle es porque has llegado al final del fichero. En el siguiente bucle lo primero que encotrarás será el fin de fichero por lo que ese segundo bucle no se ejecutará. Tienes que rebobinar el fichero tras haber llegado al final (`rweind()` o `fseek()`), o bien cerrarlo y volver a abrirlo.

Comment: Bueno, si esa es tu pregunta, sí, es totalmente posible, he removido las etiquetas [tag:c] y [tag:dev-c++] porque no son parte de esta pregunta.

Comment: Como tienes estructurado tu archivo con la lista de palabras, esta separados por saltos de línea, o tiene otro formato??

Comment: dariel si estan separadas por saltos de linea.

Comment: Necesitas guardar mientras halla salto de linea.

Comment: Bueno hice lo que me recomendo @abulafia y funciono solo en la primera palabra, es decir el while se ejecuto solo una vez.

Comment: @RosyecParrado no entiendo lo que dices amigo. tengo que agregar una decision para las lineas de salto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primero que nada**:

Estas programando en C++ (por los headers que incluyes, lo imagino) pero tu código es C liso y llano. Si bien C es compatible con C++, este último soluciona problemas muy comunes de las practicas del primero, ademas de otras cosas.

**Volviendo al problema**:

En concreto, como algunos comentarios dicen, en el segundo while vuelves a preguntar si no se llego al final del archivo, lo cual va a ser siempre cierto dado que el primer bucle lo hizo. Recuerda que cada archivo abierto tiene asociado un file descriptor e indices internos que indican en que byte del archivo te encuentras. La solución en este caso es usar alguna linea como:

```
fseek(cargar_verbos, 0, SEEK_SET)
```

o

```
rewind(cargar_verbos)
```

**Comentario aparte**: Trata que los nombres de las variables sean buenas descripciones de  la información que contienen. `cargar_verbos` no tiene sentido, ya que no carga verbos ese objeto, sino que los contiene. Un nombre más propicio seria, por ejemplo, `archivo_verbos` o `lista_verbos`.

**Solución real:**
La solución correcta, dado que estas en C++, es utilizar clases de la `stdlib` y sintaxis de C++ para resolverlo.

```
#include <iostream>    // Para imprimir por stdout
#include <fstream>     // Leer de archivo
#include <vector>      // Almacenar datos en un vector
#include <string>      // Para tener objetos string, o cadena de caracteres.

using namespace std; // Esto no es recomendable hacerlo siempre por el naming colision.

int main()
{
    auto success = EXIT_FAILURE;
    vector<string> vectorVerbos; // En C++ se usa convención camelCase

    ifstream archivoVerbos("verbos_ar.txt"); // Abrimos archivo
    if (archivoVerbos)  // Vemos si lo abrimos correctamente
    {
        string verbo;
        while (getline(archivoVerbos, verbo))
        {
            vectorVerbos.emplace_back(verbo);
        }
        archivoVerbos.close();
        success = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    // Ahora vectorVerbos contiene todos los verbos.
    // Hacer lo necesario....

    return success;   
}
```

Comment: uff gracias bro :)

Comment: @metamax dado que llevas solo dos preguntas recientes con respuestas comentarte que deberías considerar aceptar aquella respuesta que creas que soluciona mejor tu problema (si alguna respuesta lo hace por supuesto). Es la forma que SO tiene para agradecer el esfuerzo de quien responde, además de los votos, por otro lado ayuda a futuros lectores con tu mismo problema a identificar una respuesta adecuada. Para saber su funcionamiento y cómo hacerlo puedes mirarte el siguiente enlace: [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/15089). Un saludo.